# I am trying to find the origin of this rifle case and the time period it was likely made

Tags: native-americans

This black powder rifle case was passed down to me from my father. Back in the 1950's when he was a general practice medical doctor in a small town in Northern Minnesota he cared for a Native American family that was very ill. They presented him with the rifle case as a thank you. I had the external case professionally made to preserve the piece.

[image: image of a fabric/hide rifle case]

Comment: It would probably help if you could identify the town your father doctored in in the 50's. There are [11 different groups](https://mn.gov/portal/government/tribal/mn-indian-tribes/) of Ojibwe/Chippewa and Sioux found throughout Minnesota.

Comment: I'd trust an appraiser way more than me, but to my very untrained eye it doesn't look very old at all, and the style looks a lot more like what I'm seeing with Anishinaabe leather work than with Lakota.

Comment: Agree with getting a professional art dealer to look at this or maybe send a picture to the tribe in question. It could be made for the tourist market or it could be specifically made for your father.

I had a silver brooch inherited from my grandmother. It was supposedly some old family heirloom from the 19th century then one day I decided to look at the mint marks on it. It was made in the 1950s to celebrate the Queen's coronation so best not to make assumptions.

Comment: A piece with some similar features can be  seen in a [pin](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/metis-and-first-nations--121175046199375850/) showing an exhibit from the Royal Ontario Museum of an object custom made and dated to the 1880s-likely Ojibwe.

Comment: @justCal - Having looked through a bunch of such pictures today, I agree about the features. However, what it actually says is "Ojibway *or Métis*" (both of whom are Anishinaabe peoples, and both found in MN). The poster's one is a much more artistic effort than the one you found of course.

Comment: A map [here](https://www.dot.state.mn.us/tribaltraining/images/mn_reservations_map.jpg) shows that the dominant tribal group in *northern Minnesota* is  Anishinaabe (more commonly referred to there as Ojibwe or Chippewa).  So *odds are* if it was made in Northern Minnesota, it is of Ojibwe origin.

Comment: @justCal - Quite. I went with the "Anishinaabe" due to cultural similarities between closely related nations simplifying the identification task, the fact that there are *some* non-Ojibwe nations in the area, and the possibility that it was instead created in a nearby area and traded or moved there. But you're not wrong that if it is of Anishinaabe manufacture, given the location Ojibwe would be most likely.